# Why is my React/NextJS infinitely reloading if the hook throws/has error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I found a super interesting bug in my React(NextJS) application (I am not saying that is a necessarily a React or NextJS bug but I think it is a bad design pattern from them) and shared here because can happen to anyone listening to events in the app, any kind of event like serviceworker, socket etc on app mount.

The bug causes INFINITE RELOAD and my server was being ddosed by making many times same api calls.

I have this custom hook `useDidMountEffect.ts`

```
import { EffectCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

/**
 * Will run only one time after the first render
 */
export default function useDidMountEffect(func: EffectCallback): void {
    useEffect(() => {
        return func();
    }, []);
}
```

and I use it in my nextjs `_app.tsx`

```
    useDidMountEffect(() => {
        window.navigator && navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (event) => console.log(event));
    });
```

The wonderful thing was that all the browsers that had no serviceworker ended up in one infinite reload!!!

I had a hard time figuring out where the error happened but I figured this out

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener')
```

I wanted to share this as is a very interesting bug that amazed me in many years of coding, **and the question for you is:**

Why is this causing an infinite reload?
I don't understand why React hook is re-rendering when an error is thrown? I find this one design problem to be honest, because what is the point of one infinite re-render of this component if we have always an error thrown there. It just causes api calls to be done all the time and ddos the server etc. Instead I would expect the error message to be shown and not rerender all time

**You can reproduce this very easily by replacing my code with anything that throws error like**

_app.tsx

```
// other code
    useDidMountEffect(() => {
        window.notexistent.addEventListener('ok', () => { console.log('this will never be reached and your spa will re-render infinitely and make all other possible calls forever and ddos your api...')});
    });
// other code
```

package.json

```
"next": "12",
"react": "^17.0.2",
```

Make sure to yarn build than yarn start the next server, this does not happen in development mode.

The user sees the image as below

[image]

and the SPA reloads and re-renders the page all the time!(not the browser itself)!

So in the network tab I only see logo.png being requested! not the full site url therefore my monitoring system was not aware of this.

The fix was to have no errors in the useDidMount hook, and changed my code to check if serviceWorker was defined in the navigator. But still this is very fragile and bad framework design in my opinion. If we have error happening in the react hook should not re-render all the time but should have only one error message shown and thats all. Might be issue with either Next or React not sure.

```
    useDidMountEffect(() => {
        registerServiceWorker();
        window.navigator &&
            'serviceWorker' in navigator &&
            navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', listenForSwMessages);
    });
```